# Can Visual Studio 2010 do conditional breakpoints on a type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I would like to set a conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio based on what a type is assigned as.

```
var resident = user.Resident ? new ResidentUser() : new NonResidentUser();
```

I would like my breakpoint to hit when resident is of type NonResidentUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, in this case you can do condition = `user.Residen == false`, but in other cases you could do `residen.GetType() == typeof(NonResidentUser)`.

Comment: Is this in respect to in the code? Or in the conditional window in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that - set the condition to be `resident.GetType() == typeof(NoneResidentUser)`.

Comment: As per my comment to Alxandr is this in respect to code or Visual Studio conditional window?

Comment: Can you do `typeof(*arbitrary variable here*)` in C#? Not just for types?

Comment: Also...Im not sure this makes sense...user.Resident is a bool

Comment: Not in the conditional window you can't (it seems anyway)

Comment: @RyanTomlinson Take a look at my example, there I check if the bool is false (which is the condition for which you create the constructor), or the other example checks the type of the resulting resident.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that putting !user.Resident in the conditional window will fire when I want and therefore the type will be of NonResidentUser.

Comment: `!user.Resident` is exactly the same as `user.Resident == false`.